# Docker running same VPN service in different containers and load balance these requests

Tags: docker, dockerfile, vpn

I am trying to setup an image which basically runs a VPN server inside of docker. Now this VPN server by default listens on port 443. Several clients could connect to this VPN server to access corporate websites. How can I spawn multiple docker containers each running the same VPN server, but mapped to a common port 443 on the host? and load balance the request to these containers? I understand nginx is a reverse proxy, but does this also work for raw tcp/udp requests which is the use case I am trying to implement?

For now, I have one image up and running and I am using `-p 443:443` while running this container and route the incoming request to this container. I want to create several replicas of this container and then load balance the incoming tcp/udp requests.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is best solved using [Docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/). You need to create a docker service. The service allows you to create multiple instances of a container.

Swarm also has built-in support for loadbalancing. It provides by default DNS round robbin load balancing

```
docker swarm init
docker service create --replicas 5 -p 443:443 <image-name> <service-name>
```

Comment: Ended up using kubernetes replication controllers and then exposing those via services and could see the requests getting load balanced. Will have to check if the above solves my problem, since I need to study a bit on how swarm works.